# How to send email notification when a condition is met in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

These are the two condition i have

```
SELECT AStockReference, Generation_UDD03, Generation_UDD01 
FROM   dbo.masterdevicereference 
WHERE  Generation_UDD03 LIKE '%dummy%' 
AND    Generation_UDD01 NOT LIKE '%dummy%’
```

if the above condition is met email is sent to user1

if the below condition is met the email is sent to user2

```
SELECT  AStockReference, Generation_UDD03, GenerationID_UDD03,Generation_UDD01, GenerationID_UDD01 
FROM    dbo.masterdevicereference 
WHERE   Generation_UDD01 LIKE '%dummy%' 
AND     Generation_UDD03 NOT LIKE '%dummy%’ ;
```

Comment: SQL Server is an expensive choice for sending emails and there's a wealth of information on the web for exactly how to do so, and the alternatives.

Comment: You should seriously consider something outside of SQL to send emails. Either something that runs those queries every X mins and sends an email if rows are returned or use something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency for monitoring.

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL dbMail would be a good way to send the mail, you just would need to configure it. This guide should help point you in the right direction if you absolutely must use SQL Server to send an email.

[Configure Database Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/database-mail/configure-database-mail?view=sql-server-ver16)

Once you have it setup you could do something like this:

```
exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'Your profile name',
            @recipients = 'emailaddress@123.com',
            @blind_copy_recipients = 'emailaddress@123.com',
            @subject = 'Subject Line',
            @body = 'Body Text',
            @body_format = 'HTML'
```